# PyQt5, psycopg2 отобразить данные в QTableWidjet

Tags: python, pyqt5, psycopg2

Я абсолютный новичок в python. Не стала заморачиваться с драйверами QPSQL.Сделала подключение к бд с помощью psycopg2.Теперь стоит проблема как можно отобразить данные в QTableWidjet? Пробовала так,появились только линии столбцов и строк.

```
 def dbConnection(self,*args):
        try:
            con = psycopg2.connect(dbname='***', user='***', password='***', host='***', port=***)
            cur = con.cursor()
            cur.execute("SELECT * FROM table")
            data = cur.fetchall()
            a = len(data) #rows
            b =  len(data[0]) #columns
            self.ui.tableWidget.setSortingEnabled(True)
            self.ui.tableWidget.setRowCount(a)
            self.ui.tableWidget.setColumnCount(b)
            self.ui.tableWidget.setHorizontalHeaderLabels(['column_name'])
            i = 1 #row
            j = 0 #column
            for j in range(a):
                for i in range(b):
                    item = QtGui.QTableWidgetItem(data[j][i])
                    self.ui.tableWidget.setItem(j, i, item)
            self.ui.tableWidget.sortByColumn(0, QtCore.Qt.DescendingOrder) 

        except psycopg2.DatabaseError as e:
            print(f'Error {e}')
            sys.exit(1)
        finally:
            if con:
                con.close()
```

Comment: А если так: `QtGui.QTableWidgetItem(str(data[j][i]))`?

Comment: ураа,получилось!спасибо!